# How to insert a new element after an existing one with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have this [link](https://sugargoo.com/index/item/index.html?tp=taobao&searchlang=en&url=%20https%3A%2F%2Fweidian.com%2Fitem.html%3FitemID%3D2617437910) and I want to insert an new element after the 180 price tag as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZp3k.png)

My current code:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var itemPrice = document.getElementById("gsItemPrice").innerText.replace('¥', '').replace('.00', '') * 0.15;
    console.log("$" + itemPrice)
    var element = document.createElement('p');
    element.style.fontSize = '20px';
    element.innerHTML = "$" + itemPrice
    
    function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
    }

    var findPart = document.getElementsByClassName('item-pri');
    insertAfter(findPart, element);

    }, 2000);
    
  })
```

Error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertBefore')`

Notes:
The function timeout is set since the site uses a function to scrape the price of the item

Comment: Add `[0]` after `findPart` in the insertAfter line.

Comment: You probably want `var findPart = document.querySelector('.item-pri')`